# How to track student's progress remotely?

Tags: tracking

We have been providing a free remote training weekly basis, and We gave them some task/project to do. We tried to track the student's learning progress and project development using Skype and Trello. However, We are not able to keep track of their progress daily.

Is there any specific method we can follow?

Comment: Measure results, not “work” or effort.

Comment: There was no option in Trello to individually update from student side while viewing all student's record summary in the administration side as well as there was no specific way to track the update on a date basis. So, Trello doesn't work in this scenario.

Comment: Why you have to control progress daily?
In modern management, you need to make good teamwork and don't have to control individually every day. **My advice is to** to wait for results of teamwork and keep progress on that level
Best regards

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the Question. What does teamwork have to do with tracking the learning progress of a student, working individually?

Comment: We need to track the learning progress of student as pointed by @Sarov. So that we can help them to learn better and faster.

Comment: In my opinion, I will not turn the focus on daily monitoring with online tools before the learning process is organised in minimum 6 steps --> 

1. Good planning what students have to learn (without waste)
2. Good practice framework on how to learn (process)
3. Student have to have a testing phase in group one on one (peer test)
4. You have to track that peer test (report form)
5. Live Demonstration from students
6. Your review and retrospective (what can be better)

Don't do this every day! 
My suggestion is only one time in two weeks.
Don't forget culture bet any strategic.

Answer (score 1):

PM.SE is not a community for [software recommendations](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Nevertheless, considering this as a common project problem, we can offer some guidance that could be useful for you.

As the saying goes: *How to eat an elephant? One bite at a time.*

You'll need to consider two aspects: one is to have tasks to track progress on a daily basis and some sort of [online task tracking tools](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/3683/430). Once you have the team working on specific tasks that could demonstrate their obtained knowledge on the last day or so, you'll be able to obtain the info you're looking for. It's up to the students to keep such tasks updated based on their progress, and up to you to check on a timely manner for a report on how tasks are progressing. This would work as any other project. **The key is to have tasks broken down as much as possible**.