# Time Tracking in basecamp no longer supported. What are some alternatives?

Tags: software-development, pm-software, project-team, time-management

I work for a small web development company and for a few years now we have managed our time tracking through basecamp.

With the recent news that basecamp will no longer be supporting time tracking in the next version, what are some alternatives or solutions to tracking work done on projects while still being able to use basecamp as a project management solution.

The thoughts of migrating completely from basecamp are a little terrifying at the moment and I would like to transition to the new system without too much interruption to the development team.

Comment: Did you check the tools in http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3650/what-time-tracking-time-management-software-do-you-use?

Comment: Thanks there looks to be some good examples. I would prefer a solution to the basecamp issue as opposed to having to go with something else though.

Comment: Interessting to see that 4 out of 7 answers are from firsttime posters, promoting their software. Is Basecamp in trouble?(should I have posted this in meta?)

Comment: Checkout https://timebot.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the recent blog post of 37signals: http://bit.ly/xIZjSw

It seems there won't be any time tracking until the understand why customers need it:

> *Before we can commit to saying yes or no to adding time tracking in a future version of the all new Basecamp, we need to understand the problem better. It’s time to observe, study, learn, and understand how and why our customers track time.*

By filling [this survey](http://esurveynow.com/esurvey/index.php?sid=22614) you can help them.

Comment: Thanks, I went and filled it out. Hopefully they will include it. I thought it would have been a pretty popular feature in basecamp but obviously if they have left it out not as many people used it as I would have thought.

Answer (score 2):

Check [freckle](http://letsfreckle.com/), has a good set of features and a great UX/UI.

Comment: Freckle also has an API http://developer.letsfreckle.com and a growing list of available integrations.

Answer (score 2):

We use [toggl](http://toggl.com). It has a built in api to basecamp. Over time I've grown to like their interface and mobile time tracking tools.

Comment: does toggle work with the all new basecamp or just with basecamp classic?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at our [time tracking app - Paymo](http://www.paymo.biz)
It's a platform that combines time tracking with project management and billing. It can be synced with the old Basecamp (we plan on supporting the new Basecamp too once they open up the API).

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I work with the guys at Apollo, http://www.apollohq.com )

I think Apollo is a good choice, and not just because I am biased. It does everything, and it also has a great Basecamp importer.

Our basecamp importer has been working overtime lately... I wonder if Basecamp Next is the cause!

Bye,

Merc.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I am the creator of PMRobot.

I can offer a product I created after being disappointed with the old Basecamp many years ago: http://pmrobot.com

It combines the collaboration of Basecamp with true issue/bug tracking, and full time tracking and job costing.

Answer (score 1):

I always thought that Basecamp is perfect for huge enterprises. I also work for a small IT-company and we are using [TeamLab](http://www.teamlab.com/). It has the time-tracking feature in the project management module. You will find other features of TeamLab [here](http://www.teamlab.com/features.aspx). The offer a smooth transition of projects from Basecamp by the way.